# How can I show a message if the username already exists in Mysql database?

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

can anyone help me please? I am a newbie in Python Flask. I need to show a message if the "username" data already exists to avoid duplicated entries. i'm using Mysql and my table name is "users".

For example if i try to save testuser1 as a username that already exists i get
MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'testuser1' for key 'username'") I tried to do some solutions from similars asks but don't worked for me.If you can help me i will be really grateful.

Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        username = form.username.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        # Close connection
        cur.close()

        flash('You are,registered!!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
x = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = (%s)",
                          (thwart(name)))
if int(x) > 0:
   flash("That name is already taken, please choose another")
   return render_template('register.html', form=form)
else: 
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))
```

Basically, if the username exists, `int(x)` will be 1, and it’ll show an message and not save the attempt. If it doesn’t exist, it just saves it. You should also do this with email too, so users can’t have the same email.

Full Code:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        username = form.username.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        x = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = (%s)",
                          (thwart(name)))
        if int(x) > 0:
           flash("That name is already taken, please choose another")
           return render_template('register.html', form=form)
        else: 
           cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))
           mysql.connection.commit()
           cur.close()
           flash('You are,registered!!', 'success')
           return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

(Please tell me if this doesn’t work, I will try to help you resolve your problem. Also if anyone notices anything wrong, please tell me, I am also learning Flask)

Comment: What if user b inserts *while* user a is 'checking'

Comment: @Strawberry, well I think that if user b inserts and user a is checking, than it would either let user a continue or it would show an error. Even if user a got saved, I think it would run into an integrity error later. Should I fix this in my code? I don’t think this would happen though, I think the chances are very low.

Comment: I think the logic is flawed (unless bound in a transaction)

Comment: @Strawberry, how so? And how can I fix this? (I’m not very experienced in programming, I am only 13 years old and I started about a year and a half ago)

Comment: That just means your mind is fresher and quicker than mine. (The chances of a bat passing a disease to pangolin to a human are *low*, but look where we are). Your answer has been 'accepted', so I don't think you need to 'fix' it. But in general, I think methods for dealing with this kind of thing are well-established and (to the best of my knowledge) reasonably robust.

Answer (score 0):

Change/replace your unique id from mysql table 'users' so you can see your duplicate username.